# Prevent scrolling to focused input/textarea element on change

Tags: javascript, html

I made a quick sandbox here for demonstration.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button")
const topTextarea = document.querySelector("#input1")

topTextarea.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation()
})
topTextarea.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  // e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation()
})
topTextarea.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation()
})
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  topTextarea.focus({
    preventScroll: true
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

#demo {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="input1" cols="30" rows="10">asdaasdasdsadasd</textarea>
<div id="demo"></div>
<button>Scroll Top element</button>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">Bottom</textarea>
```

Issue: Focus on any of textarea on page. Scroll out of them(while they are focused) then type something. Default behavior happens, page scrolls to the focused element.

In the sandbox you can see a button which triggers focus but prevents scroll.

Is it possible to implement so that when on change happens, we prevent scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Prevent keyDown event. Gather the entered char and update your 'state'.

And you can do some calculation and scroll to the element.

For my case scrollIntoView was causing issues with our design thats why i had to scroll manually.